# Inserting custom tag in JSF Ajax response XML

Tags: ajax, jsf

Consoder the following code:

```
<h:commandButton value="do" action="#{testBacking.do}">
   <f:ajax execute="@all" render="@all" listener="#{testBacking.listener}"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

I want to have a custom tag (with value based on server logic), in the Ajax response XML, something like the following:

```
<isValidationFailed> true </isValidationFailed>
```

I can use this data to re-enable the button (which was disabled when Ajax begin, to avoid double clicks) if validation is failed.

How can I achieve this (preferably without using any JSF 3rd party libraries)?

**EDIT:**

The example code, more precisely, should be like this:

```
<h:commandButton id="myButton" value="do" action="#{testBacking.do}">
 <f:ajax execute="id1" render="id2 myButton" listener="#{testBacking.listener}"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: The concrete question is sound (and the answer isn't trivial --boils down to "You need to implement custom `PartialViewContext`, like as PrimeFaces/RichFaces did."), but the example use case is confusing. You've there a `render="@all"` which would *always* re-enable the button regardless of the outcome... You could as good just use `disabled="#{facesContext.postback and not facesContext.validationFailed}"` instead.

Comment: I have corrected and updated my post. :-)

Comment: I think I can re-render the button (just to re-enable it) and use the EL you suggested. This seems a smart solution compared to other boilerplate codes. Thanks very much.

Comment: Okay :) But as this concrete question has as far as I recall not been asked before on SO, I'll answer it anyway.

Comment: I have never thought of using facesContext in EL, but your suggestion really helps magically. Thanks again.

Comment: For more "implicit EL objects" in JSF, this overview may be helpful: [Implicit EL objects](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ImplicitELObjects). They can all be accessed the "usual" Javabean/Map-like way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is only possible with a custom [`PartialViewContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/PartialViewContext.html) which you load into your JSF application using a [`PartialViewContextFactory`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/PartialViewContextFactory.html). The custom `PartialViewContext` should in turn return a custom [`PartialResponseWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/PartialResponseWriter.html) on [`PartialViewContext#getResponseWriter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/PartialViewContext.html#getPartialResponseWriter%28%29). In this custom `PartialResponseWriter`, you should be able to add extensions to the XML response by calling [`startExtension()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/PartialResponseWriter.html#startExtension%28java.util.Map%29) and [`endExtension()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/PartialResponseWriter.html#endExtension%28%29) in [`endDocument()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/PartialResponseWriter.html#endDocument%28%29). Something like:

```
@Override
public void endDocument() throws IOException {
    Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
    attributes.put("name1", "value1");
    attributes.put("name2", "value2");
    startExtension(attributes);
    write("lorem ipsum");
    endExtension();
    super.endDocument();
}
```

This will then end up in the XML response as

```xml
<extension name1="value1" name2="value2">lorem ipsum</extension>
```

This is available and traversable by `data.responseXML` in `jsf.ajax.addOnEvent()` function.

---

Here's a full kickoff example how you could utilize it in your particular case:

`MyPartialViewContextFactory` which provides the custom partial view context:

```
public class MyPartialViewContextFactory extends PartialViewContextFactory {

    private PartialViewContextFactory wrapped;

    public MyPartialViewContextFactory(PartialViewContextFactory wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
    }

    @Override
    public PartialViewContext getPartialViewContext(FacesContext context) {
        return new MyPartialViewContext(wrapped.getPartialViewContext(context));
    }

}
```

`MyPartialViewContext` which provides the custom partial response writer:

```
public class MyPartialViewContext extends PartialViewContextWrapper {

    private PartialViewContext wrapped;
    private PartialResponseWriter writer;

    public MyPartialViewContext(PartialViewContext wrapped) {
        this.wrapped = wrapped;
        this.writer = new MyPartialResponseWriter(wrapped.getPartialResponseWriter());
    }

    @Override
    public PartialResponseWriter getPartialResponseWriter() {
        return writer;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPartialRequest(boolean isPartialRequest) {
        wrapped.setPartialRequest(isPartialRequest);
    }

    @Override
    public PartialViewContext getWrapped() {
        return wrapped;
    }

}
```

`MyPartialResponseWriter` which writes `<extension id="myextension">` with the body as JSON):

```
public class MyPartialResponseWriter extends PartialResponseWriter {

    public MyPartialResponseWriter(ResponseWriter wrapped) {
        super(wrapped);
    }

    @Override
    public void endDocument() throws IOException {
        startExtension(Collections.singletonMap("id", "myextension"));
        write("{\"validationFailed\": " + FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isValidationFailed() + "}"); // Consider a JSON serializer, like Google Gson.
        endExtension();
        super.endDocument();
    }

}
```

To get it to run, register the factory as follows in `faces-config.xml`:

```
<factory>
    <partial-view-context-factory>com.example.MyPartialViewContextFactory</partial-view-context-factory>
</factory>
```

Here's how you can access, parse and use the `<extension id="myextension">` in your `jsf.ajax.addOnEvent()`:

```
jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(function(data) {
    if (data.status == "success") {
        var args = JSON.parse(data.responseXML.getElementById("myextension").firstChild.nodeValue);

        if (args.validationFailed) {
            // ...
        }
        else {
            // ...
        }
    }
});
```

---

**However**, *your particular* functional requirement can be achieved in a different, likely simpler, manner. Just let the ajax request update the button itself and let the button's `disabled` attribute evaluate `true` when there's means of a successful postback.

```
<h:commandButton id="myButton" value="do" action="#{testBacking.do}" 
    disabled="#{facesContext.postback and not facesContext.validationFailed}">
    <f:ajax execute="id1" render="@this id2" listener="#{testBacking.listener}"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: That's simply PERFECT! Thanks once again!

Comment: +1 but instead of writing JSON format in a String directly I would recommend using JSONObject to encapsulate that: startExtension([...]);
JSONObject extensionContent = new JSONObject();
extensionContent.put("param", valueObject);
write(extensionContent.toString());